# How to connect two load cells to one HX711?

Tags: wiring, load-cell, strain-gage

I have two 5 kg load cells and one HX711. The project's goal is to connect them together, and measure the weight of the same object. I would like to get the average in order to make my calculations more accurate. I hypothesized that this is how the connections would go. I have labeled them in order to make it clear. These are the datasheets:

[Load cell](https://www.robotshop.com/media/files/pdf/datasheet-3133.pdf)

[HX711](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ForceFlex/hx711_english.pdf)

Each one of them uses a full-bridge configuration.

[image: Two load-cells one hx711]

Comment: What are you looking for?  Weight  averaged between the two sensors?  Or the sum of the weights?  Average is easy.

Comment: Use the 2nd channel.  Please see the data sheet

Comment: Dwayne, I am looking for the average between the two.

Comment: Right.  Read both channels, calculate the average.  The second channel doesn't have a programmable gain amplifier, though.

Comment: If you put two load cells under one weight, then each will only see a part of the load.  You have to sum the weight values from both cells to get the total weight.  I don't think that's what you are after.

Comment: JRE, so in order to read the second channel, would I need another HX711? You are right, I don't want to calculate a partial weight value. I want the HX711 to output one value when the input is two load cells.

Comment: I think the question to ask here is "Why do you want to average two load cells?"  As I said before, if you place two load cells under one weight, you will have to add the measured weights to get the real weight of whatever you are weighing.  An average doesn't give you anything useful.

Comment: Functionally, it may be redundant to add another load cell. However, the design of my model requires that I place two load cells on the edges of platform bed where the weight will be placed. Placing just one will make it uneven. You may say why don't you place the load cell in the middle? Design constraint.

Comment: Then an average does you no good.  You need the sum.  The only way to get the sum is to measure both cells separately.  If both cells can cover your entire weight range decently on both gain 32 and gain 64, then you could use one HZ711, then do some simple arithmetic in your processor to get the total weight.